# TextBox DataBindings Property

Tags: c#

How to know if textbox component has the property (DataBindings) informed? 
Tag: (none) 
Text: BindingSource - idclient

I need to know if this property has information.

Comment: Information how? Like if it has a databinding set in the XAML?

Comment: Yes ... I need to go looking for a form textbox and whether or not it is associated with the field of a table from the database.

Comment: ...Why can't you simply look at the code? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to know if a textbox component is bound to a field in a database table or if it is only one component of simple information in form.

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`DataBindings` is a `Collection`. You can test the content of `DataBindings` like this:

```
if (textBox1.DataBindings.Count > 0) /* do your stuff  */ ;
```

Of course this doesn't say anthing about the type or the validity of the Binding..